# How to print nouns and respective adjectives from a sentence using spacy

Tags: python, spacy

This is the python code.

```
    import spacy
    from nltk import Tree
    en_nlp = spacy.load('en')
    doc = en_nlp(u"Photos under low lighting are poor, both front and back cameras.")
    def tok_format(tok):
    return "_".join([tok.orth_, tok.tag_])
    def to_nltk_tree(node):
        if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
            return Tree(tok_format(node), [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return tok_format(node)
   [to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
```

The `output`looks like this:

```
                     are_VBP                              
        _________________|___________________               
       |     |   |   Photos_NNS              |             
       |     |   |       |                   |              
       |     |   |    under_IN          cameras_NNS        
       |     |   |       |                   |              
       |     |   |  lighting_NN           front_NN         
       |     |   |       |          _________|_________     
    poor_JJ ,_, ._.    low_JJ   both_CC    and_CC   back_NN
```

Now, I want something like,
`[(Photos,poor),(lighting,low)]` as (noun,adjective) pairs from this tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is provided inbuilt in spacy.

1. Do a dependency parsing using any spacy model.
   See the parse tree here ( do remember to switch off punctuation & phrases flags from the menu)
   https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=Photos%20under%20low%20lighting%20are%20poor%2C%20both%20front%20and%20back%20cameras.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0

[image]

2. The parsed information in the tokens would have dep ( string ) and dep_ (numeric ) attributes, which you can use to determine what adjective is being used for a noun.
3. The information that a particular token is a noun can be had using `pos` attribute of the token.

   ```
   >>> import spacy
   >>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
   >>> parsed = nlp(u"Photos under low lighting are poor, both front and back cameras.")
   >>> print(u'sentence:{0}'.format(parsed.text))
   sentence:Photos under low lighting are poor, both front and back cameras.
   >>> print(u'parsed_sentence_children::{0}'.format([(x.text,x.pos_,x.dep_,[(x.text,x.dep_) for x in list(x.children)]) for x in parsed]))
   parsed_sentence_children::[(u'Photos', u'NOUN', u'nsubj', [(u'under', u'prep')]), (u'under', u'ADP', u'prep', [(u'lighting', u'pobj')]), (u'low', u'ADJ', u'amod', []), (u'lighting', u'NOUN', u'pobj', [(u'low', u'amod')]), (u'are', u'VERB', u'ROOT', [(u'Photos', u'nsubj'), (u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'.', u'punct')]), (u'poor', u'ADJ', u'amod', []), (u',', u'PUNCT', u'punct', []), (u'both', u'DET', u'preconj', []), (u'front', u'ADJ', u'amod', [(u'both', u'preconj'), (u'and', u'cc'), (u'back', u'conj')]), (u'and', u'CCONJ', u'cc', []), (u'back', u'ADJ', u'conj', []), (u'cameras', u'NOUN', u'attr', [(u'poor', u'amod'), (u',', u'punct'), (u'front', u'amod')]), (u'.', u'PUNCT', u'punct', [])]
   >>> print(u'parsed_sentence_ancestors::{0}'.format([(x.text,x.pos_,x.dep_,[(x.text,x.dep_) for x in list(x.ancestors)]) for x in parsed]))
   parsed_sentence_ancestors::[(u'Photos', u'NOUN', u'nsubj', [(u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'under', u'ADP', u'prep', [(u'Photos', u'nsubj'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'low', u'ADJ', u'amod', [(u'lighting', u'pobj'), (u'under', u'prep'), (u'Photos', u'nsubj'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'lighting', u'NOUN', u'pobj', [(u'under', u'prep'), (u'Photos', u'nsubj'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'are', u'VERB', u'ROOT', []), (u'poor', u'ADJ', u'amod', [(u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u',', u'PUNCT', u'punct', [(u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'both', u'DET', u'preconj', [(u'front', u'amod'), (u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'front', u'ADJ', u'amod', [(u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'and', u'CCONJ', u'cc', [(u'front', u'amod'), (u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'back', u'ADJ', u'conj', [(u'front', u'amod'), (u'cameras', u'attr'), (u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'cameras', u'NOUN', u'attr', [(u'are', u'ROOT')]), (u'.', u'PUNCT', u'punct', [(u'are', u'ROOT')])]
   ```